# Team Foundation Server Restore Based Move

Tags: tfs, database-migration, database-restore, tfs-to-tfs-migration-tool

I'm trying to move my Team Foundation Server from a virtual machine to a new server and I've found a good [articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869.aspx) about doing this but it requires a lot of steps to complete.

I had found that *Team Foundation Server Backups*
of the [Team Foundation Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) can help to automate our TFS database backups and I'm wondering if there is a tool that could assist with a restore-based move. I found a tool called [Team Foundation Server Integration Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe) and I wanted to know if anyone could give me some feedback as to whether or not this will do what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TFS Integration Tools is not made for what you want, to more to migrate data coming from other SCM/ALM products.

The procedure you mentioned is the one to follow and there's no shortcut, unfortunately. The database backup feature from the TFS Power Tools will save you few minutes, but it's not much compared to the 2-4 hours that are waiting for you to complete the procedure.

Good luck and take your time !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following steps:

Backup: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253070(v=vs.80).aspx

Restore: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252458(v=vs.80).aspx